# How to use CAST in Dynamic T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am having a problem with Cast Function in the UPDATE statement. Specifically it happens in line

```
Y= CAST(SUBSTRING(@p,CHARINDEX(',',@p),LEN(@p)) AS DECIMAL(38,10))
```

. IT does not allow me to extract the data that I want. In this example, the error is "Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.". Again error is occurring at Set Y. I am trying to get X and Y out of POINT. Can someone tell me what happen to the Y statement? I am testing that Y update as following:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('2532.3,32523.2'
                ,CHARINDEX(',','2532.3,32523.2')
                     ,LEN('2532.3,32523.2'));
```

and it works. I dont know what is wrong with it. Thank you.

```
        CREATE TABLE dbo.POINTS (
         I      INT         IDENTITY NOT NULL
        ,Point  varchar(81)     NOT NULL
        ,X      decimal(38,10)  NULL
        ,Y      decimal(38,10)  NULL
        )
        GO
        INSERT dbo.POINTS (Point) VALUES ('(45.123,22.5)')
        INSERT dbo.POINTS (Point) VALUES ('(7.95,3.45)')
        INSERT dbo.POINTS (Point) VALUES ('(100.2,15.498)')
        GO



        Answer:
        DECLARE @p AS VARCHAR(81), @i AS INT =1;
        DECLARE CS CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
            Select Point FROM dbo.POINTS;
        OPEN CS
        FETCH NEXT FROM CS INTO @p;
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @x AS INT = CHARINDEX(',',@p);
            UPDATE dbo.POINTS                   
            SET X = CAST(SUBSTRING(@p,2,@x-2) AS DECIMAL(38,10)),
            Y = CAST(SUBSTRING(@p,@x,LEN(@p)-@x-1) AS DECIMAL(38,10))
            WHERE I=@i;
            SET @i =@i+1;
            FETCH NEXT FROM CS INTO @p;
        END
        CLOSE CS
        DEALLOCATE CS
```

Comment: from this string  `45.123,22.5` what value do you want to cast as decimal ???

Comment: each one of these values will be decimal. The CAST will work for each value in the 45.123, 22.5. 45.123 will be casted and inserted to X, 22.5 will be casted and inserted to Y.

Comment: a CURSOR for such a simple operation :S

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @POINTS TABLE  (
 I      INT         IDENTITY NOT NULL
,Point  varchar(81)     NOT NULL
,X      decimal(38,10)  NULL
,Y      decimal(38,10)  NULL
)

INSERT @POINTS(Point) VALUES ('(45.123,22.5)')
INSERT @POINTS(Point) VALUES ('(7.95,3.45)')
INSERT @POINTS(Point) VALUES ('(100.2,15.498)')


UPDATE @POINTS
SET X  = CAST(LEFT(REPLACE(Point, '(', ''), CHARINDEX(',', Point)-2) AS  decimal(38,10)),
    Y = CAST(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(Point, '(', ''), ')', '')
      , CHARINDEX(',', Point), LEN(Point) 
        - LEN(LEFT(REPLACE(Point, '(', ''), CHARINDEX(',', Point)-2))) AS  decimal(38,10))

SELECT * FROM @POINTS
```

**Result Set**

```
╔═══╦════════════════╦════════════════╦═══════════════╗
║ I ║     Point      ║       X        ║       Y       ║
╠═══╬════════════════╬════════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ 1 ║ (45.123,22.5)  ║ 45.1230000000  ║ 22.5000000000 ║
║ 2 ║ (7.95,3.45)    ║ 7.9500000000   ║ 3.4500000000  ║
║ 3 ║ (100.2,15.498) ║ 100.2000000000 ║ 15.4980000000 ║
╚═══╩════════════════╩════════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

Comment: thank you for answering the question, but the problem in this situation is that the creation and insertion of the table is already done before. I have to create a function or something to change the data.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I have to replace the () with '' , and problem is fixed